# Conditions yes/no

Tags: command-line, bash

I am running the following code as a part of a script (`#!/bin/bash`).

```
read -p "Do you want to make use of Thorpe volume attenuation in the watercolumn [Y/N]:" Thorpe
read -p "Do you want to include *.ati file? [Y/N]:" ati
Thorpe_att=T
ati_file=*
if [$Thorpe = Y]; then
   if [$ati = Y]; then
      echo "Usage of Thopre volume attenuation volume and *.ati file is accepted"
      sed -i "4s/''/'$interp$surf$attenuation$Thorpe_att$ati_file'/" $Mod_Filename
   else
      echo "Only usage of Thopre volume attenuation volume is accepted"
      sed -i "4s/''/'$interp$surf$attenuation$Thorpe_att'/" $Mod_Filename
   fi
else 
   if [$ati = Y]; then
      echo "Only usage of *.ati file is accepted"
      sed -i "4s/''/'$interp$surf$attenuation$ati_file'/" $Mod_Filename
   else
      echo "Neither usage of Thopre volume attenuation volume nor *.ati file is accepted"
      sed -i "4s/''/'$interp$surf$attenuation'/" $Mod_Filename
   fi
fi
```

After running it I am getting this error:

```
./mod.sh: line 50: [N: command not found
./mod.sh: line 59: [N: command not found
```

And afterwards it prints on the terminal the line :echo "Neither usage...".
Can anyone solve the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this could be greatly simplified via the use of case rather then nested if statements / test  and you may want to use Yy) or Nn) and *) . See http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the spaces in your test commands. This part:

```
if [$Thorpe = Y]; then
   if [$ati = Y]; then
      ...
```

Should be

```
if [ $Thorpe = Y ]; then
   if [ $ati = Y ]; then
      ...
```

Without the spaces, the shell expands the value of `$Thorpe` to `N` and tries to run `[N`, which it sees as a command. It doesn't recognise this as a valid command, and outputs the error you're seeing.

Personally I prefer to use the `[[ $Thorpe = Y ]]` Bash builtin, rather than `test`, (`[ $Thorpe = Y ]`), it deals with unquoted strings better and has a more obvious use of && and || operators.

Answer (score 1):

The error is the missing space. The `[ ]` construct always needs spaces, so `[foo]` is wrong but `[ foo ]` is correct. So, in your case, change

```
if [$Thorpe = Y]; then
```

to

```
if [ $Thorpe = Y ]; then
```

On a more general note, why would you ant to make the lives of your users so hard? Stopping a program's execution and requiring users to laboriously and manually type out input is very bad design. Especially when asking for a file name which could easily be given using tab completion and is very likely to be entered wrongly.

Instead of forcing users to answer questions, write your script so that it can handle command line options or, at least, make it so that any arguments passed are automatically assumed to be whatever values you're asking for.